# How can i get all the links of a webpage and click one by one using selenium

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

How can i get all the links of a webpage and click one by one using selenium

//Code

```
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.HRS.com");
    List<WebElement> MyList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a")); 
    for(WebElement Element : MyList)
    {
    Element.click();  ----> m getting an error (IN 2 ITERATION) stating 
                           "Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has 
                            changed since it was looked up" 

    }
```

Can any one help me out ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue with phpUnit+Selenium. getXpathCount('//a') returns 25. However, isElementPresent('//a[3]') onwards keeps returning false.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the link you are following the link, which invalidates the elements you have located. You need to either go back to the page:

```
driver.navigate().back();
```

After doing such you will need to refresh the elements in the list, meaning your current loop construct likely would not work well.

Another option is to check in the following way:

```
//Might need to do some extra work if this is a relative link
HttpURLConnection httpConn = new HttpURLConnection(element.getAttribute("href"));
URLConnection = httpConn.openConnection();
if (conn instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
  HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
  Assert.assertTrue("Invalid link on page.", http.getResponseCode() < 400);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the most tedious tasks, IMO, for a test engineer, is manually verifying links. We can automate most of the process and as long as we have the URL's for where we are expected to land after clicking the link, we can verify this functionality using Selenium and a little bit of JS.

In the below example we first navigate to our desired website and then use Selenium's `getEval()` function to execute JavaScript that gathers all the links on the page (anchors) and saves them in a comma separated list. This list then gets split and pushed into an array. We then iterate through the list of links in the array clicking on each one and then navigating back to the starting page using `go_back`.

Example below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
use Test::WWW::Selenium;
use Test::More "no_plan";

my $sel = Test::WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost",
                                    port => 4444,
                                    browser => "*iexplore",
                                    browser_url => "http://www.google.com/");

$sel->open_ok("/", "true");

$sel->set_speed("1000");

my $javascript = "var allLinks = this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementsByTagName('a');
                 var separator = ',';
                 var all_links_texts = '';

                 for(var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
                       all_links_texts = all_links_texts+separator+allLinks[i].href;
                 }
               all_links_texts;";

# Get all of the links in the page and, using a comma to separate each one, add them to the all_links_texts var.
my $link_list = $sel->get_eval($javascript);

my @link_array = split /,/ , $link_list;

my $count = 0;

# Click on each link contained in the array and then go_back
# You can add other logic here like capture and store a screenshot for example
foreach my $link_name (@link_array) {

    unless ($link_name =~ /^$/){

        $sel->click_ok("css=a[href $= $link_name]");

        $sel->wait_for_page_to_load("30000");

        print "Clicked Link href: $link_name \n";

        $sel->go_back();

        $count++;
    }
}
print "Clicked $count URL's";
pass;
```

The above can be easily modified to do much more than just click on the links. And of course nothing beats a good pair of eyes on the intended landing pages for the links clicked.

Our full blog post is here: [Get all links and click on each one](http://vgp-miami.blogspot.com/2011/08/get-all-links-and-click-on-each-one.html)